# Adding JSON array to DynamoDB Item

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I understand that I can create "Lists" only from primitive data types, so look at my (Node.js using AWS Document Client) code as pseudo code.  My objective is to attach a JSON ***array*** to an item so that I can later retrieve/update/delete the device (and corresponding data) from the customer's record.  I understand I may be able to use Maps to do this, but I'm a beginner and the documentation regarding how to do that using document client is unclear to me.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
var deviceData = {
    'deviceID': deviceID,
    'attributes': [
        {'firmwareVersion': firmwareVersion},
        {'productID': productID},
        {'knickName': 'New Device'},
        {'dateAdded': (new Date()).getTime()}
    ]
};

var newCustomerData = {
    TableName: process.env.customerMasterFile,
    Key: {
        'email': email
    },
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
    UpdateExpression: 'ADD #device :device SET #customerEmailDomain = :customerEmailDomain, #friendlyName = :friendlyName, #created = :created, #updated = :updated',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#device': 'deviceList',
        '#customerEmailDomain': 'customerEmaiDomain',
        '#friendlyName': 'friendlyName',
        '#created': 'createAccountTime',
        '#updated': 'updateAccountTime',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':device': docClient.createSet([deviceData]),  // I know this is incorrect...
        ':customerEmailDomain': customerEmailDomain,
        ':friendlyName': friendlyName,
        ':created': (new Date()).getTime(),
        ':updated': (new Date()).getTime()
    }
};

docClient.update(newCustomerData, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, JSON data will be persisted as Map on DynamoDB. If you store JSON array on DynamoDB, it will be stored as **"List of Map"** data type on DynamoDB which will make it difficult to update, delete, retrieve without knowing the index of the List data type (i.e. device). It is not recommended to use **"List of Map"** if you need to accomplish update/delete without knowing the index of list (i.e. index of an array).

1) Changed to SET for all attributes including device

**To store single JSON object as Map which will allow to update/delete without knowing the index of an array:-**

```
var params = {
    TableName: process.env.customerMasterFile,
    Key: {
        'email': email
    },
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #device = :device, #customerEmailDomain = :customerEmailDomain ,#friendlyName = :friendlyName, #created = :created, #updated = :updated',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#device': 'deviceList',
        '#customerEmailDomain': 'customerEmaiDomain',
        '#friendlyName': 'friendlyName',
        '#created': 'createAccountTime',
        '#updated': 'updateAccountTime',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':device': deviceData,
        ':customerEmailDomain': customerEmailDomain,
        ':friendlyName': friendlyName,
        ':created': (new Date()).getTime(),
        ':updated': (new Date()).getTime()
    }
};
```

**Sample device as Map:-**

[image]

**Alternate Approach:-**

- Add `device id` as sort key of the table
- The attributes `email` and `device id` forms the unique combination for an item on DynamoDB
- You can accomplish the update/delete easily with this data model

Comment: thanks for your thoughtful response.  As I understand it, Sort Key added to my table with a Primary Key creates a sort of composite identifier.  It is possible in our database not to have a device (ergo no deviceID) assigned to an account.  Would I then try to store a 'null' object in deviceID in the case, for example, where user 1) creates account where no device is attached or 2) modifies/updates/deletes such that all attached devices are removed fro user's account?

Comment: No, that is not possible. Sort key is must for an item.

Comment: Sort Key value may be non-unique vis-à-vis the rest of the table (unique within the Item), I take it.  I think I may then write in a dummy object that would allow me to easily/rapidly get the item with a {'email':email, 'deviceID': 'dummy'} pair.  Or, is there a simpler/better/easier way that I am overlooking?

Comment: Yes, this should be fine. But you can't update the sort key value once the item is created. An user will have a item with dummy device object item when account is created without device. When the device is attached, you may need to create a new item for the email and device id. Hope that is fine.

Comment: OK, so the 'dummy' device stays attached forever, we then create it when the primary key (is email) is first created... fine.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding the 2nd bit: We couldn't create a new email/deviceID pair in the Table as the email is the Primary Key.  I'd look to attach another deviceID to the deviceList.  forgive me if I missed something obvious.

Comment: No, you can create. The combination of Partition key and Sort key should be unique. You can have multiple items with same email id having different device ids (including dummy id).

Comment: ... because (as I even mentioned earlier) these key/value pairs would be a **composite** key!  Understood now.  I just have to wrap my code around this paradigm.  Thanks for the help!